# converting a string of comma seperated values to a multidimensional javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp

In my getOptions.jsp file, I have created a string with jstl.

```
<c:set var="options" value="Maximize,Redo,RemoveFormat,Save" />
```

This string should now be transformed into this format (which is, if I am correct, a multidimensional javascript array (or is it json?)).

```
[['Maximize', 'Redo','RemoveFormat','Save']]
```

I have to do this because this format is expected by a javascript method located in another .jsp (showToolbar.jsp),

```
function handleToolbar(options) {
          //toolbar = [['Maximize', 'Redo','RemoveFormat','Save']];  the expected format!
          toolbar = options;
    }
```

So my question is, how do I transform the comma-seperated string 'options' into the format that is expected in the 'toolbar' variable in order to pass it from one jsp to the other and pass it as a parameter of the handleToolbar function.

Note: I guess it is not ideal to use javascript in a jsp but that I cannot change because I inherited the code.

Thanks alot in advance, I've been searching for hours for the solution and can't find it.

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
var myString = "Maximize,Redo,RemoveFormat,Save";
var myArray = [myString.split(',')];
```

The result is an array that has 1 element in it. That 1 element is this array:

```
['Maximize', 'Redo','RemoveFormat','Save']
```

So, `myArray` is:

```
[['Maximize', 'Redo','RemoveFormat','Save']]
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that worked. I had tried out this solution before, but what confused me was that a console.log of myArray would not show the square brackets, but just Maximize,Redo,RemoveFormat,Save

Comment: Great, I'm glad to be of help! Please consider accepting this answer ;-)